# Declaring symbols in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am using this code:

```
item(one, 50, 40).
item(two, 80, 70).
item(three, 100, 55).
item(four, 50, 45).

maxMeanStudy:-  
    findall(M,item(_,M,_),L),
    max_member(Max,L),
    writeln(Max),!.
```

To access middle value of item, I have to access it using `item(_,M,_)`. 
This is OK if there are a few entries only. But if there are many entries it is difficult to enter `item(_,_,_,_,_,M,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_)` every time.

Is there any way that I declare the structure initially as `item(Name, Val1, Val2)` and then I can just access it with `item(Val1)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be interesting is this code that can work on every arg of a predicate :

```
item(one, 50, 40).
item(two, 80, 70).
item(three, 100, 55).
item(four, 50, 45).


argStudy(Predicate, Arity, NumArg, Study_Name, V):-
    compound_name_arity(L,Predicate,Arity),
    findall(Args, (L, L =..[_|Args]), L_Args),
    maplist(nth1(NumArg), L_Args, Lst),
    call(Study_Name, Lst, V).
```

For example :

```
 ?- argStudy(item, 3, 2, max_list, V).
V = 100.

 ?- argStudy(item, 3, 2, min_list, V).
V = 50.

 ?- argStudy(item, 3, 2, sum_list, V).
V = 280.

 ?- argStudy(item, 3, 1, sort, V).
V = [four, one, three, two].
```

Answer (score 7):

Just define an auxiliary predicate like so:

```
md_(M) :-
   item(_, M, _).
```

This way you only have to write that (potentially) large number of underscores *once*.

Sample query using SICStus Prolog 4.3.3:

```
| ?- md_(M).
M = 50 ? ;
M = 80 ? ;
M = 100 ? ;
M = 50 ? ;
no
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the arity (num. of arguments) is a distinctive trait of clauses, you could shortcut your code adding

```
item(Val1) :- item(_, Val1, _).
```

but it seems a short sighted choice, for maintenance.

Handling relations with many attributes (columns) has always been a problem in Prolog, since it doesn't specify how to declare metadata.

It's not too difficult to build such layer, using for instance the ISO builtin [arg](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=arg/3)/3. Or look into library([record](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=record)). OTOH, SWI-Prolog took a radical departure choice, implementing a non standard extension [dicts](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=dicts).

Comment: It should be noted that the overhead of the argument access predicates such as `item/1` can be eliminated in systems providing a term-expansion mechanism by automatically rewriting those calls into calls to the `item/3` predicate.

Answer (score 1):

Easy:

```
argValue(Index,Value,F/A) :-
    functor(Pred,F,A),
    Pred,
    arg(Index,Pred,Value).
```

Now select, by index, which argument to obtain:

```
?- argValue(3,Val,item/3).
Val = 40 ;
Val = 70 ;
Val = 55 ;
Val = 45 ;
Val = 40 ;
Val = 70 ;
Val = 55 ;
Val = 45.

?- argValue(2,Val,item/3).
Val = 50 ;
Val = 80 ;
Val = 100 ;
Val = 50 ;
Val = 50 ;
Val = 80 ;
Val = 100 ;
Val = 50.
```

Comment: Note: I wrote more clauses to item/3 than you in your example

Comment: In (Index,Value,F/A) , the Index is the column number starting from 1, and F is name (here 'item') and 3 is total number of columns. Is that right?

Comment: Index is the column number starting from 1, left to right, as you say.

Comment: F is the functor of the involved predicate, and A is the arity.

Comment: just to explain: item/3 denotes a predicate named "item" which accepts three arguments. For example.

Comment: Thanks for the information. BTW, you can edit your comments in first 5 minutes. Too many comments are discouraged here. You can also add explanation in your answer to make it more complete and delete all these comments.